# How to return values in a formula, from rows of latest 4 nonconsecutive dates recorded

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

Using an `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` formula we want to **capture the latest 9 records (rows) over a period of nonconsecutive dates**.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(sort(vlookup(query({row(EBPP!D:D),sort(EBPP!A:E)},Q15,0), 
{row(EBPP!D:D),sort(EBPP!A:E)},{2,3,4,5,6},0),4,0),R8,5)
```

Points to consider:

- Cell `Q15` holds the query
- Cell `R8` will hold the part we need for the dates.

Please have a look at the image.

[image: latest 9 records]

---

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VwZUddNawtJznV75NbEZ9IYTFTDm3dhM_b2hWYX2aS4/edit?usp=sharing) added.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sorry no. I just made up the data, made a photo and deleted it. Is there something I can explain to you?

Comment: @user0 Hold on. I will make one.

Comment: @user0 Please have a look at the spreadsheet. For the moment sheet `RESULTS` is editable so you can use it for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally came up with an eloquent solution using the `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`, `SORT`, `QUERY` functions.

**This is the final formula, small, flexible** (both variables out of the formula), **row expandable, robust** (works with empty cells):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(
   QUERY(A2:E, "select * where D >= date '" & text(J21, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"),
     4,FALSE,5,),M21,5)
```

You can try and play with it on **[the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VwZUddNawtJznV75NbEZ9IYTFTDm3dhM_b2hWYX2aS4/edit?usp=sharing)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
={A1:E1; QUERY(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(D:D), SORT(A:E)}, K1, 0), 
 {ROW(D:D), SORT(A:E)}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0), 4, 0), 
 "where Col4 <="&INDEX(QUERY(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(D:D), SORT(A:E)}, K1, 0), 
 {ROW(D:D), SORT(A:E)}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0), 4, 0), 
 "select Col4 
  order by Col4 desc"), 2, 1)&"
    and Col4 >="&INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY({ROW(D:D), SORT(A:E)}, K1, 0), 
 {ROW(D:D), SORT(A:E)}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0), 4, 0), 
 "select Col4 
  order by Col4 desc")), 5, 1)&"
  limit 9", 0)}
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

[image: 0]

```
={A1:E1; QUERY(QUERY({A2:E}, K1, 0), 
 "where Col4 <= date'"&TEXT(MAX(QUERY({A2:E}, 
 "select Col4 
  order by Col4 desc", 0)),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col4 >= date'"&TEXT(TO_DATE(INDEX(UNIQUE(QUERY({A2:E}, 
 "select Col4 
  order by Col4 desc", 0)), R9, 1)), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  limit "&R8, 0)}
```

Comment: Sorry it took me some time to get back to you. I was testing as well as studying the formula. **It works great for my question**. Still. There seems to be a **glitch when the limit hits 10**. Do you know why? Could you have a look at it? You can try it on the spreadsheet.

Comment: There is also another glitch is when **the `Dates difference` hits 10**. It will not give more results no matter how high it gets. Also. Could it still work using an `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` as we started it originally and if so, how?

Comment: tested with `limit 10` and works fine. as for the VALUE error when changing `5` to 10 - thats kind of normal coz the whole data sample does not have 9 unique dates. and no. solving this only with arrayconstrain is not doable

Comment: I feel we are a bit lost about the dates range. On column `E` there is a total of 30 recorded dates/records. `(30 dates - duplicate dates)=22 dates`. So to give an example to the question. _"What should we change so we could have results from the latest 15 dates limited to 25 records?"_ These are our **2 variables (unique dates and records) that should be taken out of the formula (each to its own cell) as to be easily altered**. Hence in the original question _"Cell `Q15` holds the query"_ and _"Cell `R8` will hold the part we need for the dates"_.

Comment: and again, this is not how it works. this is the full output from the blue data table. and you want to filter out all except last 4 unique dates and then limit the whole array to display only max of 9 rows of those 4 unique dates. therefore you need to find last date, then you need to find 4th unique date from top of the latest dates. when you have these two variables you can wrap your initial formula (from the picture) into QUERY and filter out the array (on the picture) based on those two variables (dates). and after that you can have your limit in R8 or simple "limit 9" in the query formula

Comment: picture for above comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZbn1.png

Comment: You are correct about the image which depicts **though**, our then efforts/experimenting. That is why I had the [pic of DESIRED RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpdT.png) added. As you can see your provided formula will not produce the _desired result_. I do admit I misled you when I hastily commented _"It works great for my question"_. Now on the subject. We did take both variables out of the formula (Dates difference, Limit). Can you please help on altering it so we can get the results we are after?

Comment: @marikamitsos answer updated